# CesiumJS: How can I get the midpoint of a line on the globe?

Tags: cesiumjs

I have a [sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

The relevant code is:

```
const testLines = [
                    [ [ -150,  45 ], [  150,  45 ] ], // <---
                    [ [  150,  40 ], [ -150,  40 ] ], // --->
                  ];

testLines.forEach( ( line ) => {
  const endpoints = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray( [ ...line[0], ...line[1] ] );
  const e1e2      = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
  const halfe1e2  = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
  const midpoint  = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
  
  Cesium.Cartesian3.subtract( endpoints[1], endpoints[0], e1e2 );
  Cesium.Cartesian3.multiplyByScalar( e1e2, 0.5, halfe1e2 );
  Cesium.Cartesian3.add( endpoints[0], halfe1e2, midpoint ); 
 
  const carto = Cesium.Cartographic.fromCartesian( midpoint );
  const lon   = Cesium.Math.toDegrees( carto.longitude );
  const lat   = Cesium.Math.toDegrees( carto.latitude );
  
  console.log( `${lon}, ${lat}` );
})
```

The output is:

```
180, 49.11979677835345
180, 44.111242494938004
```

The latitudes are wrong. The first one should be 45 instead of 49.11 and the second should be 40 instead of 44.11.

I have also tried using the `Cesium.Cartesian3.midpoint` and `Cesium.Cartesian3.lerp( endpoints[0], endpoints[1], .5, midpoint )` functions directly, but they produce the same result.

I have also tried:

```
  const a = new Cesium.Cartographic()
  const b = new Cesium.Cartographic()
        
  Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees( line[0][0], line[0][1], 0, a );
  Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees( line[1][0], line[1][1], 0, b );
 
  const globeCalc = new Cesium.EllipsoidGeodesic( a, b )
  const midpoint = new Cesium.Cartographic()
        
  globeCalc.interpolateUsingFraction( .5, midpoint )

  const lon   = Cesium.Math.toDegrees( midpoint.longitude );
  const lat   = Cesium.Math.toDegrees( midpoint.latitude );
  
  console.log( `${lon}, ${lat}` );
```

but the result is the same.

What needs to change so this will work? Or, I a misunderstanding some fundamental concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept I was missing was the difference between a [geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) and [rhumb line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhumb_line).

from [Great Circles, Geodesics, and Rhumb Lines](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/great-circles-geodesics-and-rhumb-lines.html#):

> A great circle is the shortest path between two points along the surface of a sphere, a geodesic is the shortest path between two points on a curved surface, and a rhumb line is a curve that crosses each meridian at the same angle

Cesium provides some rhumb line computations with [EllipsoidRhumbLine](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/EllipsoidRhumbLine.html?classFilter=EllipsoidRhumbLine).

I can get the midpoint I was expecting with [interpolateUsingFraction](https://interpolateUsingFraction)

[Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)